# Want to render the data received via sockets in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, render

Here is the React code:

```js
var Dashboard = React.createClass({
  loadLineFromServer: function(line){
    console.log("inside loadlinefromserver");
    var socket = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8000/');
    socket.onopen = function(){
      console.log("websocket opened");
      var send_data1 = "Point A: " + line.x1 + "," + line.y1 +" \n";
      var send_data2 = "Point B: " + line.x2 + "," + line.y2;
      socket.send(send_data1 + send_data2);
    }
    socket.onmessage = function(event){
      console.log("websocket on message");
      var websocket_data = event.data;
      this.setState({data: websocket_data})
      console.log(websocket_data);
    }.bind(this),
    socket.onerror = function(e){
      console.log("error in websocket");
      console.log(e.message);
    }
  },
  handleFormSubmit: function(line){
    this.loadLineFromServer({x1: line.x1, y1: line.y1, x2: line.y1, y2: line.y2});
    var url = util.format('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/line/');
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      crossDomain: true,
      dataType: 'json',
      data: line,
      type: 'POST',
      success: function (data) {
        this.setState({data: data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function (xhr, status, err) {
        this.setState({data: line});
        console.error(url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {data: []};
  },
  componentWillMount: function() {
  },
  render: function(){
    return(
      <div className="dashboard">
        <Navbar inverse>
          <Navbar.Header>
            <Navbar.Brand>
              <a href="">TrainingInduct</a>
            </Navbar.Brand>
            <Navbar.Toggle/>
          </Navbar.Header>
        </Navbar>
        <Dashform onFormSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit} />
        <h1>{this.state.data}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

I don't find the line coordinates rendered on the screen. The websocket_data appears on the console only, whereas I setState it so that it gets displayed on the screen. Any leads as to how to go about rendering the data?

Edit1: I missed the semicolon after **this.setState({data: websocket_data})**

Now,the points get displayed momentarily but again due to:

```
getInitialState: function() {
      return {data: []};
 },
```

The points diappear. Can someone help how to get around this issue??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the issue with the code. Actually due to the failure of the 'POST' ajax call, the error method was getting called and that was setting the data to NULL again. I commented out that line and now it is working fine.

```
     error: function (xhr, status, err) {
     //  this.setState({data: line});
       console.error(url, status, err.toString());
     }.bind(this)
```